# || vs or keywords

Tags: c++

Simple, probably easy to answer question. What is the difference between || and or in something like an if statement.

Simple examples:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int x = 8;

    if(x == 8 or 17){
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int x = 8;

    if(x == 8 || 17){
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
}
```

These seem to work the same way for me. They both compile and they both display "Hello World!" I've always used || and didn't even know about or. Do they do the same exact thing? Or is there a slight difference like using \n or endl where one acts slightly different. Sorry if this is a really simple question.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I hope you know that's equivalent to `if ((x == 8) || 17)`. It is always `true`.

Comment: or is not a keyword in c++ it is a macro defined as `#define or ||`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Luchian says, there is no semantic difference. A [draft of the latest C++ standard says](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), in the "Keywords" section:

> Furthermore, the alternative representations shown in Table 5 for
>   certain operators and punctuators (2.6) are reserved and shall not be
>   used otherwise:

```
and     and_eq  bitand  bitor  compl   not
not_eq  or      or_eq   xor    xor_eq
```

But there could be a difference for anyone reading your code.  The `||` operator for "logical or" goes back decades. The alternative representations are newer.

They were introduced at least as early as the 1998 C++ standard (I don't know if pre-ISO C++ had them). It's at least conceivable that you might encounter a C++ compiler that doesn't recognize them, but if so it's going to be an old enough compiler that you'll have other problems. C introduced similar identifiers in its 1995 amendment (but only with `#include iso646.h>`).

At least in C, and probably in C++, these alternate representations, along with digraphs and trigraphs, were introduced to cater to systems with character sets that don't include all the characters that would otherwise be required for C and C++:

```
{ } [ ] # & | ^ ~ !
```

With the introduction of more modern character sets, particularly Unicode, such systems are increasingly rare.

But as far as I can tell, they're rarely used in code (I don't think I've ever seen any code that uses them), and some C++ programmers might not be aware of them.  I believe your code will be more legible if you use `||` rather than `or`.

And as Luchian also says, `(x == 8 || 17)` doesn't mean what you might expect from, say, English grammar.  It doesn't mean "x is equal to either 8 or 17"; it means `((x == 8) || 17)`; `17` is treated as a condition by itself, not compared to `x`.  Possibly you wanted to write `(x == 8 || x == 17)`.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler doesn't recognize alternative tokens. You have to include a special header that adds a few of them via macros.

Comment: @bames53: In MS Visual C++ 2010 Express, `or` is a syntax error, but it's accepted (with the correct meaning) if you "Disable Language Extensions" (`/Za`). I guess the "extension" is allowing `or` et al as identifiers. Adding `#include <iso646.h>` or `#include <ciso646>` introduces the alternative forms (at least the ones that are identifiers), but gives me some bizarre run-time failure that I'm too lazy to diagnose.

Comment: I think the "extension" is *forbidding* `or`, you disable the extension to get the standard-conforming mode that accepts them. It's a good idea to similarly reject trigraphs in your own code as an "extension", because you never want to write code that contains one.

Answer (score 1):

It's the exact same, it's an alternative operator. You can find a full list [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative).

Also, note that `x == 8 or 17` returns true always. It doesn't check whether `x` is either `8` or `17`.

Comment: I'm aware that it's always true. I just wanted a very simple example that incorporated it. And thanks for the answer. That's what I though but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @NekkoRivera I want to highlight that you might consider it's always true only because you have set `x` to 8.  However, what Luchian means is that if `x` was set to 42, the statement would still evaluate to true.  If you are only interested in the case where `x` is either 8 or 17, you must explicitly state `x == 8 || x == 17`.  The statement `17` on its own is counted as a boolean truth.  Just want to make sure you're on the same page here. =)

Comment: @paddy Ohhhh! Haha I didn't realize that I did that. Opps it's wrong in example 2 also because I copied and pasted haha.

Comment: @NekkoRivera I'd come back to the post and accept Keith's answer. You don't have to accept the first correct answer, but the best one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between them,both of them do the same thing

Comment: This is not an answer.